# Several ports(8080,8009) required by tomcat v7.0 server at localhost are already in use

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, port

I built a new web project and added a JSP file to test if it works with the tomcat service. The IDE is Eclipse 3.7 for Java EE, I ran the project, then it showed:

> Several ports(8080,8009)required by tomcat v7.0 server at localhost are already in use...

So I changed the two ports and ran it again(I'v restarted the tomcat service),but it still didn't work,it showed:

> Server tomcat v7.0 server at localhost failed to start.

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm.. on which base OS you 're working . Windows or Linux

If it is Windows and you have installed tomcat as a service.. then go to run box in start and type services.msc and then in the opened window you will get to see many service running or stopped in the system. Find out the Tomcat Service and stop it.  Then again just run your project again and it will automatically prompt you to start server.